How to list/manage credentials stored in VSCode safe storage?
For some time now, Visual Studio Code has switched to the Electron safeStorage API. I used to be able to see all the credentials in my keychain. Now I only see the safeStorage encryption key. Is there a way to see the credentials stored in VSCode itself? How would I remove an existing secret without fiddling with some SQLite database in VSCode's data folder?
